# How to show steepest descent will not converge to local but to global minima of funtion.

Tags: gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

for a function $f(x, y) = 0.5*x^2 +0.25*y^4 −0.5*y^2$.

Show that there are infinitely many starting points for which gradient (steepest) descent will not converge to a
local, let alone global, minimizer of f.

I know the global minimizer of this function is (x,y)=(0,1) and (0,-1) and (0,0) is inflection point. But I don't understand how should I show for many starting points steepest descent will not converge to a local, let alone global, minimizer of f.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What if you start on the line $y=0$?

Comment: Hi..I know if starting point is y=0, then in next iteration y=0 and i will stuck at y=0. But, i don't understand how should i show ?

Comment: If $y = 0$, $\partial f/\partial y = 0$ so you stay on $y=0$.  No local or global minima of $f$ are there.